# Solved: CiviRules 2.1 and CiviVolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1 not working with CiviCRM 5.4.0

Tags: wordpress, civivolunteer, civirules

I'm using WordPress 4.9.8 and I've upgraded our CiviCRM to 5.4.0. After that CiviRules 2.1 and CiviVolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1 seem not working.

**1. CiviRules 2.1**, when click **New rule**, it backs to CiviCRM homepage

CiviRules> **Find Rules**> could find Rules but can not edit existed Rules. It only shows empty windows like this:
[image]

CiviRules> CiviRle Tags work ok

**2. CiviVolunteer** 4.7.31-2.3.1

Volunteers> New Volunteer Project: Go back to CiviCRM homepage

Volunteers> Manage Volunteer Project: Go back to CiviCRM homepage

Volunteers> Configure Roles> work ok

Volunteers> Configure Project Relationship work ok

Volunteers> Configure Volunteer Settings: Go back to CiviCRM homepage

Volunteers> Volunteer Interest Form: Go back to CiviCRM homepage

Volunteers> Search for... Go back to CiviCRM homepage

Please check and help to fix

---

**Solution**: I've follow Aidan's comment: Clearing the caches by go to Administer > System Settings > Cleanup Caches and Update Paths > Cleanup Caches
And all works ok now

Comment: Have you tried clearing the caches again?  Administer > System Settings > Cleanup Caches and Update Paths > Cleanup Caches

Comment: Oh, I've acted like you said and all seems work again, Thanks!

Comment: Could you please update your question with what you did and mark it as solved?

Comment: @JaapJansma-CiviCooP I've edited my question but I still don't know how to mark it as solved

Comment: Hi @ToanLuong - I've added my comment as an answer.  The way to mark your question as solved here on SE is to add the 'green tick' next to my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many post-upgrade issues like this can be resolved by clearing the caches.  It should be taken care of by the upgrade process, but it's worth trying it again.

You can clear the caches in various ways including: `Administer > System Settings > Cleanup Caches and Update Paths > Cleanup Caches`